# Calculation of Row entries with more than 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

I would like to get sum of all the oranges in a row for a particular year and particular month and specific user. I tried couple of options with AND & OR. I am not sure how to user AND in more than 3 conditions. Below is an example grid for which e.g desired result is 2 for first row
attached example is in pic format and one of the query I am trying with is

**Query**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `usr_fruit`
where (d1="orange" or d2=" orange " or d3=" orange " or d4=" orange ") 
and year=115 and usrNo= 1 and month=2
```

**table looks like this**

```
usrNo   d1     d2     d3     d4     month   year

1     orange  apple  apple   orange  2       115
1     apple   apple  apple   apple   3       114
2     apple   apple  apple   orange  2       115
2     apple   apple  apple   apple   3       114
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Is the query failing? Returning the wrong results?

Comment: when i use month=2 then it shows only 1 but if i remove month=1 then it gives result as 2..

Comment: You have two rows with Oranges in them. Why isn't this correct?

Comment: what i am looking is - answer to show result as 2 -- number of oranges in a row with usrNo =1 , month= 2,   year =115

Comment: but there is only one row with usrNo =1 , month= 2, year =115.? How can you expect 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need `'orange'` count in `d1, ... d4` columns, try this query:

```
SELECT (d1='orange') + (d2='orange') + (d3='orange') + (d4='orange') AS count_in_row
 FROM `usr_fruit`
 WHERE year=115 AND usrNo= 1 AND month=2
```

Here `(d1='orange')` has value 1 when condition is true, and 0 otherwise. See: [MySQL Equal operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal)

Comment: I am not sure to ask a follow up question in this chain trail or not..but suggest me as i m new to SO....what would be the query to show only maximum value with the same query...means in my table i would like to select count of maximum year value..my desired answer is 2 for usrNo=1 and month=2 with max(year) and don't want to get data related with year 114

Comment: Max value can by calculated in [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html): `(SELECT MAX(year) FROM usr_fruit WHERE usrNo=1 AND month=2)` and you can place this subquery in place of `115`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query like below using a `OR` condition probably

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `usr_fruit`
where 'orange' IN (d1,d2,d3,d4)
and (year=115 
or usrNo= 1 
or month=2);
```

Comment: it works fine only with row 1, rest row data is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to your query may be like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `usr_fruit` where 'orange' IN (`usr_fruit`.`d1`,`usr_fruit`.`d2`,`usr_fruit`.`d3`,`usr_fruit`.`d4`) and 
(year=115 or usrNo= 1 or month=2);
```

Comment: this query is working good with usrNo=1 but if i try with usrNo=2 then it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarifying comment:

> number of oranges in a row with usrNo =1 , month= 2, year =115

You could utilize the way MySQL interprets a boolean "true" expression as a `1` and a "false" as a `0` when put in numerical context:

```
SELECT (d1 == 'orange') + (d2 == 'orange') + (d3 == 'orange') + (d4 == 'orange')
FROM   usr_fruit
WHERE  usrNo = 1 AND month = 2 AND year = 115
```